# Add specific permissions fails, adding user group succeeds

Tags: 2010, permissions, groups

User A needs access to a list. This list is already uninherited from the parent site.

I give User A read permissions, User A still cannot access list.

I add User A to a group with the same permissions (but also has permission to whole site), User A can access list.

Why is this? Is there something I'm missing? I am using the link directly to the list, so it should work, but user is given access denied until I add to specified group.

Comment: Can you check whether the User A has read access to the whole site when you are not adding it to a group? Is it just this particular list that he is not able to access?

Comment: I dont want him to have read access to the whole site, just the list that is in the site. I use the direct link to the list and he should be able to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are there are some elements on the page or master page which the user cannot access. Check the permissions for the group, what other permissions does the group have? Is your list using a lookup into another list (which that user would need read permission to as well).

You can also try running Fiddler to view the traffic requests when logged in as User A, see what is being called from where.

HTH

Comment: @Mike: To make sure that whether its your master page, you can simply make the v4.master as the default and try accessing the list. If it works, then scrutinize your master page for permission settings.

Comment: How would I troubleshoot the masterpage to what exactly they do not have access to so I can fix it?

Comment: Using Fiddler should identify what data the page is trying to access, and then returns an access denied

Comment: With SharePoint it doesn't. It just says an access denied page.

Comment: Is it a custom master page? Check the permissions of the styles library in the root web.

Comment: It is a custom master page. The permissions of the styles library is set to read and exec from NT Auth\Authenticated Users, so that can't be it.

Comment: How can I tell what on the custom masterpage is set to different permissions?

Comment: I dont think there is an easy way to determine this. If you masterpage is referencing lists directly, or assets like images, css, etc. check each element individually.

Comment: I could use more help with this on how to determine that..

Comment: If you want, email me your master page and i can see if there is anything obvious, davidlo at magenic dot com. Or one thing to do, and will be tedious, is to remove your custom elements, one at a time.... or go back to the standard master page and start applying your customization.

Comment: I think a long time ago I actually COPIED v4.master word for word and changed around some things. The master page I have is edited to be almost word for word to v4, and still no dice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2706/discussion-between-david-lozzi-and-mike)

Answer (score 0):

I have to add to this answer. Once I made sure that SharePoint Designer allowed my custom masterpage and viewed it as indeed a masterpage (was a blank Content Type), the permissions worked fine. Previously, the masterpage that I previously had whenever I opened this ticket was 'invalid' and SharePoint wanted me to change it. Once I created a new masterpage and copied over the changes from the old masterpage, saved it, published it, and approved it, the permissions per list worked correctly so that the user could have access to a list without having permission to the whole page. The previous masterpage said access denied to the specific list URL for the user that had read access.